# Create the same user on xmpp server when a user is created in a rails 3.2 app

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, xmpp

I am building an application in which front end is iPhone and I am using ROR as my backend with mongoDB as my database. It is a kind of chatting application for which I am using jabber protocol and XMPP server. Now I want that when a user is created in my rails app, the same user should be created on the XMPP server. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal situation is to have only a single source for users and configure your XMPP server to use that same service.

For example it is common to have an XMPP server authenticate against LDAP, then all user management is delegated to the LDAP server.  The XMPP server doesn't handle user management at all, but defers any user related queries to LDAP.

This would ultimately be more reliable than trying to keep two separate systems in synch.  If the user management in your case is custom (which it appears to be), it might mean you will also have to add a custom module/plugin to your XMPP server (you haven't mentioned which one you are using) to use that service.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use a single source only now. I am trying to run shell command "system" to run my desired query. It works fine when I do that from my server but when I do the same from my rails app I get returned value as "nil" or sometimes "false"

Comment: I found the answer by following this link [link](http://siddharth-ravichandran.com/category/ejabberd/). This solved my problem also I have to add a line "include Jabber" at the top of my file.